# Rendering data before the component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, httpclient

I want to use my data loading from a HttpClient service in the html template, but it looks like the data is rendering after the component so I use the directive ngIf to resolve the problem but it doesn't work ! Any help ?

The component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyserviceService } from '../myservice.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-forms',
templateUrl: './forms.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./forms.component.css']
})
export class FormsComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit() {
this.getBook()

}

constructor(private service : MyserviceService) {
}

Booknames :any

getBook () {
return  this.service.getBookNames().subscribe((data)=> {this.Booknames = data , 
  console.log(this.Booknames)}) ;
}}
```

The component.html :

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Enter your name</mat-label>
         <input matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Name-linechart</mat-label>
       <input matInput>
 </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="BookNames">
    <mat-label>xAxis-linechart</mat-label>
    <mat-select >
      <mat-option  *ngFor="let book of BookNames" >
        {{book}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

When I run it the field "xAxis-linechart" doesn't appear !

Comment: try removing the return keyword in getBook(), and please share the JSON you are getting from service(that you are storing in this.Booknames)

Comment: @ShlokNangia no it still not working

Comment: try `*ngIf="Booknames"` instead of `*ngIf="BookNames"`, same for the `*ngFor` iteration

Answer (score 0):

I replace *ngIf="Booknames" with *ngIf="BookNames", I do the same for *ngFor and it works ! :)